# How to scale my function by a constant

Tags: r

so i created a function for 5000 intervals and i would like to scale it by 0.02

```
N=5000
T=5
t0=0
t<-seq(t0, T, length = N + 1)
B<-function(t){
    (1-exp(-0.03*(5-t)))/0.03
    }

W<-0.02*B
Error in 0.02 * B : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

However, i get this error. is there any possible way to scale my function?

Comment: Try : `B<-function(t, scale){
    scale*((1-exp(-0.03*(5-t)))/0.03)
    }`

Comment: And t is a base-function in R. It's bad practice to name your variables like base-functions. And I think you mean `B(t)`, as `B` alone is not a function call.

Comment: Use B as a function: `W<-0.02*B(t)` and it will be scaled.

Comment: @Heroka So is `scale`. I've found `t`/`T` unavoidable when working with panel data, myself. Using `tt` instead is too annoying.

Comment: @LyzandeR Holy molly thanks alot! that was great help! i'm really new to this programming thing and you're a saviour!

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! this community is awesome

Comment: @Donkeykongy You re welcome, my pleasure. And to be fair this is actually a good question for a first question from a new user (keep posting reproducible questions and you ll be getting answers most of the time).